# Submitting pyspark script to a remote Spark server?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

This is probably a really silly question, but I can't find the answer with Google. I've written a simple pyspark ETL script that reads in a CSV and writes it to Parquet, something like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)
df = sqlContext.read.csv(input_filename)
df.write.parquet(output_path)
```

To run it, I start up a local Spark cluster in Docker:

```
$ docker run --network=host jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

I run the Python script and it connects to this local Spark cluster and all works as expected.

Now I'd like to run the same script on a remote Spark cluster (AWS EMR). Can I just specify a remote IP address somewhere when initialising the Spark context? Or am I misunderstanding how Spark works?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a spark session by specifying the IP address of the remote master.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://<ip>:<port>").getOrCreate()
```

In case of AWS EMR, standalone mode is not supported. You need to use yarn in either client or cluster mode, and point HADOOP_CONF_DIR to a location on your local server where all files from /etc/hadoop/conf are present. Then setup dynamic port forwarding to connect to the EMR cluster. Create a spark session like:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'cluster').getOrCreate()
```

refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-submit-spark-job-remote-cluster/

Comment: It doesn't seem possible according to the docs: "It's not possible to submit a Spark application to a remote Amazon EMR cluster with the following command: SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://<master url>:7077”).setAppName("Word Count");" - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-submit-spark-job-remote-cluster/

Comment: Ah sorry, I seem to have skipped over the last couple of lines of your question. Did you try port forwarding? Are you still having problems submitting the job?

Comment: Edited the answer for future reference.

Comment: If using pyspark, should deployMode be 'cluster' or 'client'?

Comment: If it's Spark Standalone, you have to go with _client_, as the standalone mode does not support _cluster_ for Python applications. If you're using YARN, it depends on your setup and whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client).  

In _cluster_ mode, the client can give initiate the application at the Application Master and go away whereas in _client_ mode the Spark driver runs in the client process, and the Application Master is used only to request resources from YARN.

Comment: From the docs:
"A common deployment strategy is to submit your application from a gateway machine that is physically co-located with your worker machines (e.g. Master node in a standalone EC2 cluster). In this setup, client mode is appropriate. In client mode, the driver is launched directly within the spark-submit process which acts as a client to the cluster. 

If your application is submitted from a machine far from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers and the executors."

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I have decided to go with Spark on Kubernetes (EKS) instead, which was a bit simpler to set up.